# In wxWidgets, is there a way to avoid buttons showing only partially when window is resized?

Tags: c++, user-interface, layout, wxwidgets

I am just starting with [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/) and I could not find a way to make the buttons inside a sizer to always show at their full size

ie. the user should not be allowd to lessen the window size too much.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK eventualy I got the answer. The sizer that is attached to the frame must call [SetSizeHints()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxtoplevelwindow.html#wxtoplevelwindowsetsizehints)

EDIT : It is correct to call it for the top level window, as suggested below.

Comment: No, this is just wrong. `SetSizeHints()` should only be called on TLW. And the previously mentioned `SetSizerAndFit()` does it for you. But even if you call it manually yourself, it still makes no sense to call it on any sizers other than the one associated with the TLW.

Answer (score 1):

[wxTopLevelWindow::SetMinSize](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_top_level_window.html#ac491313979c027b67526786b06167e6d) allows you to set the minimum size that your window can be resized to. You can always make it small programmatically if needed.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not prohibit the user from making the window smaller than the minimum size. It is only used for the initial size of the window.

Answer (score 0):

Use GetSizer()->Fit() when you finish adding controls to layout.

http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.9.4/classwx_sizer.html#abad9cedc0cbe9ade2c799da23462d17e

Just noticed that you want to prevent the **user**. rather than the sizer, from shrinking the window too far.

The way to do that is to handle the resize event.  In the handler check the new size against the minimum size, and if it is too small, than do not allow the resize to occurr.

Answer (score 0):

Sizers distribute the available size among their elements. If there is not enough space available, something bad will inevitably happen, i.e. at least some controls will not have enough size.

To prevent this from happening you must ensure that the top level window is big enough initially and can't be resized by the user to a smaller size. The easiest way to achieve it is to call `SetSizerAndFit(sizer)` when associating the sizer with the top level window. This will do both of these things at once.

Comment: Well, almost. The top-level window should be able to resize, but not become way too small. It's a little different from having a fixed size.

Comment: Calling `SetSizerAndFit()` doesn't make the TLW fixed size. It does exactly what you need.